# Ajax CORS request with basicauth gives 401 error on browser

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot, cors

I know there are lots of posts regarding the same problem, but none of it resolve my issue.

I have a springboot microservice application with the following API

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping({ "/sample" })
public class SampleController {


    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://192.168.0.31:8080", allowCredentials = "false", allowedHeaders = "*")
    //@CrossOrigin//(allowCredentials = "false")
    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome" , method=RequestMethod.POST, produces={"application/json"})
    public JSONObject getWelcomeResponse(@RequestParam Map<String,String> request){
        JSONObject response=new JSONObject();

        response.put("response", "Welcome user");
        System.out.println("Complterd ****");
        return response;
    }
}
```

properties file

```
server.port=8081
security.user.name=test
security.user.password=test123
#security.basic.enabled=false
```

And my client code is

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://192.168.0.31:8081/sample/welcome",
                type : "POST",
                crossDomain:true,
                crossOrigin:true,

                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    // Use BASIC Authentication
                    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("test:test123"));
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    alert(status, errorThrown);
                    // Error block
                    console.log("xhr: " + xhr);
                    console.log("status: " + status);
                    console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                }
            })
            .then(function(data, status, xhr) {
                alert(data);
                console.log("xhr: " + xhr);
                console.log("status: " + status);
                console.log("data: "+ data);

                $('.message').append(JSON.stringify(data));

            });
        });
```

When I disable the basic auth, The cors request is works fine. But if it enabled it gives 401 preflight request error.

I have tried  @CrossOrigin with default as well as customized way also. But getting the same error. Also tried with a filter class like below.

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyAppConfigurations  implements Filter {

       @Override
       public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)

                     throws IOException, ServletException {

              HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

              HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

              if("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(httpRequest.getMethod())) {

                     httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                     System.out.println("filterde response");

              } else {

                     chain.doFilter(request, response);

              }
       }
}
```

Can somebody help me to figure out, what I am missing on this code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create `CORS FILTER` for your `Spring MicroService`

```
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;


@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            addCorsHeader(response);
            if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            } else {
                filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addCorsHeader(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200"); // Update with yours
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please accept as answer if my answer solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add @CrossOrigin before class like

```
@RequestMapping({ "/sample" })
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://192.168.0.31:8080")
public class SampleController {
```

try adding in your `/welcome` Rest Controller

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CORS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-request), the CORS preflight request must be accepted without any authentication.

You have to configure your web server or Spring Security to disable authentication on all `OPTIONS` requests related to preflight.